# Which folder is the files downloaded from method startDownloadingUbiquitousItem?

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, icloud-documents

What folder are the files downloaded from the method?

I can't find where the files downloaded from this method are. According to the documentation it downloads only when necessary, but I can't find where the icloud files are downloaded.

```
FileManager.default.startDownloadingUbiquitousItem(at: fileURL!)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are downloaded to the URL you give it, which should be in the ubiquity container for your app.